# Scraping : How to exclude specific tag with bS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I hope you're well do you know how I can exclude a specific tag in scraping?

```
#Récupération des ingrédients
            try:    
                ingredientsdiv = soup.find("div", class_="c-recipe-ingredients")
                ingredientsbloc = ingredientsdiv.find("ul", class_="c-recipe-ingredients__list")
                ingredients = [re.findall(r'^(?:(\d+)\s([^\W\d_]*))?(.*)', item.text.replace("\n", "").strip()) for item in ingredientsbloc.find_all("li", {"class": ""})]
            except Exception as e:
                ingredients = None
```

here is the HTML code

```
<div class="c-recipe-ingredients"><ul class="c-recipe-ingredients__list" data-id="258101"><li>10 cl de lait de coco</li><li>1 cuillère à café de poivre vert</li><li>Huile de pépin de raisin</li><li>Fleur de sel</li><li>4 brins de menthe</li><li>2 c&amp;œligurs de laitue</li><li>4 citrons verts</li><li>12 tomates cerise</li><li>4 oignons nouveaux</li><li>600 g de filets de bar                                <span class="c-recipe-ingredients__item--sponso u-relative"><span><a target="_blank" href="https://www.pourdebon.com/bar-sauvage-d38?utm_source=750g&amp;utm_medium=autopromo&amp;utm_content=Top10_750g_Autopromo&amp;utm_campaign=750g_autopromo_recette" class="u-some-link u-color-pourdebon xXx" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'autopromo-pdb-ingredient', 'clic', '600\x20g\x20de\x20filets\x20de\x20bar')">                                            En direct des producteurs sur
                                            <img src="/bundles/cuisinewebsite/img/partner/logo-pourdebon.png" alt="Logo Pourdebon" itemprop="logo"></a></span></span><script>
                                    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                                        ga('send', 'event', 'autopromo-pdb-ingredient', 'view', '600\x20g\x20de\x20filets\x20de\x20bar', {
                                            nonInteraction : true
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script></li></ul></div>
```

There is a sponsoring link, like that:

```
<a target="_blank" href="" class="u-some-link u-color-pourdebon xXx" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'autopromo-pdb-ingredient', 'clic', '600\x20g\x20de\x20filets\x20de\x20bar')">                                            Lorem ipsum 
                                            <img src="/bundles/cuisinewebsite/img/partner/logo-pourdebon.png" alt="Logo Pourdebon" itemprop="logo"></a>
```

I would like to exclude the sponsoring link text in my scraping  (json file) :) Do you have any idea?

Comment: what exactly do the `li` elements look like, you need to show us a few of the ones you want to include, and those that you do not.

Comment: sorry I do it right now

Comment: it seems that `li` tag includes both text and other tags, what do you want the final `ingredients` to look like?

Comment: Like that: 

"ingredients": [
            [
                [
                    "10",
                    "cl",
                    " de lait de coco"
                ]
            ],
[
                [
                    "1",
                    "cuill\u00e8re",
                    " \u00e0 caf\u00e9 de poivre vert"
                ]
            ],

Comment: without: 
[
                [
                    "600",
                    "g",
                    " de filets de bar                                                                            En direct des producteurs sur                                                                                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {                                        ga('send', 'event', 'autopromo-pdb-ingredient', 'view', '600\\x20g\\x20de\\x20filets\\x20de\\x20bar', {                                            nonInteraction : true });});" ]

Comment: I save it in a json file

Comment: so you do not want that final `li` tag at all?

Comment: your current code does not include all that `document.addEventListener` in the resulting list, the final element of your list looks like `[('600', 'g', ' de filets de bar             En direct des producteurs sur')]` - please re check your output and clarify your question

Comment: I want all li without the <script> text and the sponso link (En direct des producteurs sur')

Comment: @Chase I've just found the solution to take off the script text :) I've made mistake sorry. So right now I only get:
[
                    "600",
                    "g",
                    " de filets de bar                                                                            En direct des producteurs sur"
                ]

Comment: with others li :) but still En direct des producteurs sur in one li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all intents and purposes, if you want to get the text from elements like `li` but not the nested `a` and `script` element(s) - you should use [`NavigableString`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring)

So, instead of `.text` - you should use this function-

```py
import bs4

...

def get_only_text(elem):
    for item in elem.children:
        if isinstance(item, bs4.element.NavigableString):
            yield item
```

Then call this function outside and join the entire generator to get the final string-

```py
ingredients = [re.findall(r'^(?:(\d+)\s([^\W\d_]*))?(.*)', ''.join(get_only_text(item)).strip()) for item in ingredientsbloc.find_all("li", {"class": ""})]
```

Output of `ingredients`-

```py
[[('10', 'cl', ' de lait de coco')],
 [('1', 'cuillère', ' à café de poivre vert')],
 [('', '', 'Huile de pépin de raisin')],
 [('', '', 'Fleur de sel')],
 [('4', 'brins', ' de menthe')],
 [('2', 'c', '&œligurs de laitue')],
 [('4', 'citrons', ' verts')],
 [('12', 'tomates', ' cerise')],
 [('4', 'oignons', ' nouveaux')],
 [('600', 'g', ' de filets de bar')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to extract exactly using `li` tag?
If you want to extract text contained within `li` tags, just add `.text()`

```js
find_all("li", {"class": ""}).text()
```

Above statement will get rid of js & link within anchor tag and return you with text value.

Comment: This will not get rid of the text within the nested tags

Comment: Thks bro for taking care of my question